# Issues Converting Mule Tomcat WAR to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mule

I've been going through the process of converting my Mule project to a Spring Boot application, and have hit a snag I can't seem to figure out.

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot so I'm not sure if my issues lie with it, or with the way I'm doing my mule stuff.

Here is my sample project I've been trying to convert: https://github.com/JustinBell/mule-webapp-example

When I deploy this to a tomcat instance it works great, the issue comes when I try to run it as a Spring Boot application I'm getting this exception:

```
ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Just as a note I'm moving from mule 3.6.1 to 3.7.0-M1 as that's required (from my understanding) to use Spring Boot.

I've tried looking around for support on this issue which seems to pretty common, but none of the suggestions I've found have solved the issue.

Thanks for any help with these issues!

Comment: I notice `servlet:inbound-endpoint` in https://github.com/JustinBell/mule-webapp-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/mule-webapp-demo.xml : what Servlet container will you use? Does Spring boot load the `web.xml` in a Servlet container?

Comment: My understanding was that there is an embedded tomcat instance with Spring Boot that would be used, but your question made me double think that, so I'm looking into how the embedded instance works to make sure it's doing what I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that aren't quite right in your code as it stands.

If you want to build a web app with Spring Boot, you'll typically want to add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`. This provides, among other things, the embedded servlet container:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Your app's dependency on `org.mule.transports:mule-transport-servlet` pulls in a very old version of Tomcat's Coyote module. You need to exclude this to avoid it clashing with the up-to-date dependency that's provided by `spring-boot-starter-web`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>coyote</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Your `Application` class is trying to run `MuleContextInitializer` which it also declares as a bean. It should be running `Application.class`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Your `Application` class is also in the default package. You should avoid using the default package as it will cause Spring Boot to scan then entire classpath looking for your application's classes and configuration. Moving it into a package of its own to stop this from happening.

Lastly, the app fails to launch as it's looking for a file named `mule-config.xml`. Renaming `mule-webapp-demo.xml` to `mule-config.xml` addresses this.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth walk through! That seems to have fixed all the issues, and was very informational.

Answer (score 1):

I believe autodelete is an Enterprise feature, perhaps you are using ftp rather than ftp-ee.

Comment: Interesting, I'll strip that part out of the question so I can do some research on that.